# How do you create small div squares that auto distributes itself per row?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i know this is simple but I can't seem to figure it out at the moment.

My page displays sets of info separated via divs and styled to look like "boxes" 
[image]

I will be displaying different number of boxes (items) dynamically, so I wanted the page to display each box horizontally ala "text wrapping" style where each box maintains its dimensions but is evenly distributed per line depending on the available viewport...

I tried to do this the bootstrap way but the columns auto extend / fill the horizontal space, based on the coloumn sizing... w/c is a waste .. my boxes are 50x50 pixels and i just need all those boxes to spread out evenly.

And additionally, i wanted the boxes centered.. where if there are only 3 small boxes to display they'd be at the center, not left most.

my code so far

HTML

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12">
<div class="terminal_entry"> <span class="" > blah  </span></div>
<div class="terminal_entry"> <span class="" > blah  </span></div>
<div class="terminal_entry"> <span class="" > blah  </span></div>
<div class="terminal_entry"> <span class="" > blah  </span></div>
<div class="terminal_entry"> <span class="" > blah  </span></div>
</div>                                                            
</div><!-- /.row -->
```

CSS

```
.terminal_entry {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #cccccc;
    margin: 3px;
    padding: 5px;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @deebs said, try

```
display: inline-block
```

for your elements and set the parent to

```
text-align: center.
```

Here's a JS Fiddle showing the functionality you want: http://jsfiddle.net/stroz/EB5bC/

Answer (score 0):

You could use a repeater or loop to create the elements (divs with class 'terminal_entry'), and as for styling try adding:

```
terminal_entry {
    Display: inline-block;
}
```

And if you make the width of the class 'col-xs-12' about 165 to hold three divs (with 50px width and 5px padding per div) that should limit to three per row. And to center try margin: 0 auto. So style for that container is:

```
col-xs-12 {
    width: 165px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I havent tested and I'm doing this from my phone, but thats the idea.